# Assembly Language storing characters in a loop

Tags: assembly

The code that follows compiles and will only produce the first letter of my name in the putString from the loop.  it needs to produce all the letters of my name so that it is stored

```
jmp  firstline

openMsg db "Program by John Piper", 13, 10  
lenOpenMsg = $ - openMsg

myName  db  "John Piper"   
myNameLen = $ - myName  
myName1 db  ?  
myNameLen1 = $ - myName1  
myName2 db  ?  
myNameLen2 = $ - myName2  

firstline:

    mov  SI, offset openMsg 
    mov  CX, lenOpenMsg 
    call putStrng   
    call crlf


    mov  si, offset myName
    mov  cx, myNameLen
    call putStrng
    call crlf
    call crlf


    mov  si, 0
    mov  cx, myNameLen
LoopTop1:  
    mov  dl, myName(si)  
    xor  dl, 0AB  
    mov  myName1(si), dl  
    inc  si  
    loop LoopTop1  


    mov  si, offset myName1
    mov  cx, myNameLen1
    call putStrng
    call crlf
    call crlf



    mov  ah, 04c
    int  021

include ioProcs.inc
```

Comment: can you provide code for putStrng? also what is your assembler? I must say I have never seen constant like 0AB (doesn't mean it can't exist though), I would expect rather 0xAB or 0ABh

Answer (score 0):

`myName1 db  ?` reserves just one byte for `myName1`. Thus, `myNameLen1` will be 1 and `putStrng` will write one byte. Also, you will override memory behind `myName1`. Reserve place for `myName1` and `myName2` as much as consumed by `myName`:

```
...
myName  db  "John Piper"
myNameLen = $ - myName
myName1 db  myNameLen DUP (?)
myNameLen1 = $ - myName1
myName2 db  myNameLen DUP (?)
myNameLen2 = $ - myName2
...
```